# React useState run the useEffect at run-time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect, use-state

I've a function (loadList) in my component to load my list data from API

And at run-time I want to get all data, so I've this code:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    loadList();
}, []);
```

And I've a state (changedFilter) to handle reload list again :

```js
useEffect(() => {
    loadList();
}, [changedFilter]);
```

But after checking the DevTools > Network tab, I've 2 XHR request in this scenario ...

Apparently by default React consider initial values for useState as a change and run the second useEffect with sense on changedFilter state ...

Is any trick to handle it ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to run only on changedFilter?

Comment: Please also share the code that alters `changedFilter`

Comment: Just remove the first effect. Effect hook runs on mount, and on every render cycle thereafter, so they ***both*** run on component mount. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect

Answer (score 0):

`useEffect(() => { loadList(); }, [changedFilter]);`

will also be trigger on first render as well along with first `useEffect` therefore your fist useeffect with `[]` dependency is redundant. Only second useEffect might solve your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the useEffect from running on initial render in 2 ways.

**First:** Use a ref to track initial render

```
const initialRender = useRef(true);
useEffect(() => {
    if(!initialRender.current) {
        loadList();
    } else {
        initialRender.current = false;
    }
}, [changedFilter]);
```

**Second:** Check for the existence of changedFilter if its not defined or empty initially

```
useEffect(() => {
    if(changedFilter) { // Change it to changeFilter.length > 0 if its an empty array initially
       loadList();
    }
}, [changedFilter]);
```